# solved(Measure theory)

Tags: probability-theory

We say that a subset $A$ of $(0, 1)$ is open if $A = B \cap (0, 1)$, where $B$ is some open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $C$ denote the collection of open sets in $(0, 1)$. Prove that the Borel $\sigma$-field on $(0, 1)$, i.e. $\sigma(C)$, is the same as $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R} \cap (0, 1) := \{B \cap (0, 1) \mid B \in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sigma(C)$ is contained in $\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\cap(0,1)$. To prove the other inclusion, note that $\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\cap(0,1)$ is a restriction of the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. You can use the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem in the following way:

Let $S=\{B\in \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}: B\cap(0,1)\in\sigma(C)\}$. Then $S$ is a sigma algebra (and therefore  $\pi$ system) which contains the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$. The $\pi-\lambda$ theorem states that $S=\sigma(S)=\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$. This proves that the other inclusion is true.

$\pi-\lambda$ theorem:

[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#:~:text=the%20π-λ%20theorem%20is,determine%20the%20joint%20law%20of&text=have%20the%20same%20distribution%20if,same%20joint%20cumulative%20distribution%20function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#:%7E:text=the%20%CF%80-%CE%BB%20theorem%20is,determine%20the%20joint%20law%20of&text=have%20the%20same%20distribution%20if,same%20joint%20cumulative%20distribution%20function).

This is  my first post here so I apologize in advance if the text is unreadable.